# add new Tab to default Tabs in microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to add new tab to default Tabs in Microsoft Teams , it will same as picture Tab Calendar , it has tab Calendar contain two tab Details and tab Scheduling Assistant. how to add a new Tab in Default Tab , i read any doc of microsoft Teams
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs about custom tab and website tab but not yet solution for this task, please support for me Thanks
[image]

Comment: please support for me , thanks , I need the solution very urgently

Comment: Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/teams-apps-in-meetings)? try if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Moving answer from Comment:

You can enable [Pre-meeting app experience](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/teams-apps-in-meetings#pre-meeting-app-experience) by [creating apps for Teams meetings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/create-apps-for-teams-meetings?tabs=json).
[image]

Note: This feature is in [Public Developer Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/dev-preview/developer-preview-intro#enable-developer-preview).